# how to distribute build folder using SvelteKit

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I've just compiled a SvelteKit application with the [node-adepter](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node) issuing `npm run build`

this is the output I get

```
$ ls build/
assets  index.js pre-rendered
```

But When I try to execute it I get:

```
$ node build/index.js 
(node:103550) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/ubuntu/tmp/build/index.js:62
import http from "http";
^^^^^^
```

Which I could solve it creating a package.json file like this:

```
{
        "type": "module"
}
```

But then I get import errors unless I copy the whole node_modules folder to the build folder

Is this the right way to distribute the app?

I just want to copy the necessary files and start it with `node build/indes.js`

BTW I'm using SvelteKit 1.0.0-next.132 and node 16.6.1

Comment: Can you share what adapter you are using to generate the build?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I added the reference to the node-adapter, which is what I'm using

Comment: Try running "node build". Also mention what version of node you are using

Comment: I've updated the question qith the SvelteKit and node version I'm using, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

`import * as http from 'http';` instead of `import http from 'http';`

You are probably trying to import a Non-ESM module using the ESM syntax which will not work.

Comment: whould you mind elaborating a little bit about it?

Comment: For further reading: https://redfin.engineering/node-modules-at-war-why-commonjs-and-es-modules-cant-get-along-9617135eeca1